# how to convert ado net destination to ole db destination in SSIS ?

Tags: sql-server, ssis, dts

i have dts package Contains a large number of ADO Net Destination . 
how to replace ado net Destination with OLE DB Destination ?

Comment: Manuel work if you want to replace the ssis component

Answer (score 0):

You have to do it one by one, there is no easy and safe way to do this programmatically.